# Positioning Labels in pie3D

Tags: r, statistics

Trying to change label positions in pie3D, did read all help available, and here advises given to lads looking for the same, but can't  find any real solution to choose position of the label, anyone knows if there is any real solution around ?

example:

```
> mydata
        0         1 
0.4082073 0.5917927
```

library(plotrix)

```
labels <-  
  c( paste('No: ',round(100*mydata[1],1),'%',sep=''),
     paste('Yes: ',round(100*mydata[2],1),'%',sep=""))
pie3D(mydata, labels=labels,labelcex=1.1, labelrad=1.4, explode=0.05, theta=1,radius =1,start=1.5,
      main='Result',col=c(cols[2],cols[9]),col.main='blue')
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Get the real position of your labels:

```
   pos<-pie3D(mydata, labels=labels,labelcex=1.1, 
             labelrad=1.4, explode=0.05, theta=1,radius =1,
             start=1.5,main='Result', col=c(cols[2],cols[9]),col.main='blue')
```

then:

```
> pos
[1] 2.782421 5.924014
```

Then change positions one after other (you can play a bit):

```
pos[1]<-2.1
pos[2]<-5.3
```

check if new positions are set correctly

```
> pos
[1] 2.1 5.3
```

then add this to parameters using "labelpos=pos" as shown below

```
labels <-  
  c( paste('No: ',round(100*mydata[1],1),'%',sep=''),
     paste('Yes: ',round(100*mydata[2],1),'%',sep=""))

pie3D(mydata, labels=labels,labelcex=1.1, labelrad=1.4, 
      explode=0.05, theta=1,radius =1,start=1.5,
      main=''Result'',col=c(cols[2],cols[9]),col.main='blue',
      labelpos=pos)
```